# Formula to extract specific cells in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to find a way to extract multiple values from a specific range of cells that always change, the only Identifier that Could be noticed is that the cell I need to extract the value from is above the Cell that has GOOD as text typed.

I have Put the Cell I need to extract in bold.

Please note that there would be hundreds of these not just 2. and the data is always changing the only Identifier is that the cell I need is above the GOOD cell.

I have tried many things however nothing seems to do the trick because the info is always changing.

```
Sep 12, 2019 ・ 19:50:46
5fjfbgfdxb9
Joe
doe
CRY
$0.00
$212.54
$220.00
**$212.54**
GOOD
gateway
212.54

Sep 12, 2019 ・ 01:28:04
djynjytygj565
Joe
Doe
CRY
$0.00
$173.26
$180.00
**$173.26**
GOOD
gateway
173.26
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
=transpose(ArrayFormula(regexextract(textjoin("|",1,A:A), rept("(\$[0-9.]+)\|GOOD.+", 2))))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(textjoin("|", 1, if(A2:A="Good", A:A,)), "|")))
```

[image: Screenshot]

To make the output numeric, try

```
=transpose(ArrayFormula(regexextract(textjoin("|",1,A:A), rept("(\$[0-9.]+)\|GOOD.+", countif(A:A, "Good")))+0))
```

and format the column of the output properly (e.g. as currency).

Answer (score 0):

try simply like this:

```
=QUERY({{""; A:A}, {A:A; ""}}, "select Col1 where Col2 = 'GOOD'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Please add some description along with your answer.

Comment: Amazing Didn't even come to mind to use query, much appreciated .

Comment: Is there a way I can return as a value and only to count if the Text CRY is in the data so if there was another word instead ot will not count that field.

Comment: not sure I understood you, pls explain in more detail

Comment: So I need the query to be as a value so that I could add all the values together, and I also need it only to calculate the value if there is that text CRY as sometime there will be another text which I don't need to add. Like sort of 2 values has to be "Good " and has to be "CRY". Is this abit more clear?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({{""; A:A}, {A:A; ""}}, "select Col1 where Col2 matches 'Good|CRY'", 0)*1)`

Comment: This didnt work either could you explain how this array works player0?{{""; A:A}, {A:A; ""}}

Comment: sure, `{{it takes the whole column A and inserts a blank cell above it},{then it takes again whole column A and places 1 empty cell below it}}` = so the final result is that you have 2 columns displaced by one row. a small scale example would be: `={{"";1;2},{1;2;""}}` ... here is a demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=309956956

Comment: Great I get it, and is it possible to make the output numerical?

Comment: as already mentioned... to get numeric just wrap it in `ARRAYFORMULA` and multiply it by 1 - `=ArrayFormula(QUERY({{A:A;"";"";"";""}, {"";"";"";"";A:A}}, "select Col1 where Col2 matches 'ZELLE'", 0)*1)` - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=309956956